# kable_styling() : Not in outer par mode

Tags: latex, r-markdown, kable

I'm using a Rmd program with the 4.0.2 R version.

Here is a sample of the code:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
## packages de mise en forme des tableaux
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)
source("utils/Functions.R")
resultat_1 <- load_and_correct_csv("resultat_1.csv", 1, 5) 

```

\begin{figure}[H]%[!hbtp]
```{r resultat_1, echo=FALSE}
options(knitr.kable.NA = "nd")
kable(resultat_1
      , "latex"
      , booktabs = F
      , linesep = ""
      , align = "crrrrr"
      , row.names = F
      , col.names = names(resultat_1)
      , format.args = list(big.mark=" ", decimal.mark=",")
) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("repeat_header")
                , full_width = F
                , font_size = 9
  )
```
\end{figure}
````

And here is the error I get:

```
! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.
```

If I remove the kable_styling instruction, the code is compiling well and producing a valid pdf.

What do you think ?

Comment: Can you make a [mre] and show your .log file?

Comment: I updated the post with a minimal reproducible example as you requested!

Comment: I can't test your code because I don't have the csv file, but I think the stuff inside latex environments like `figure` are normally not interpreted as r code. As you anyway don't allow latex to find a nice place for the figure, do you actually need the `figure` environment?

Comment: Thanks it worked! By deleting the begin/end `figure`, the code compiled without error. What I need to understand now is why the code was compiling (with `figure`) on others computers: do you think it could be related to some different versions of R, kable, etc. ?

Comment: I'm just a latex user, no idea what might have changed in r, kabel etc.

Comment: It was the version of package kableExtra which was different. Thanks !